# Package specific to figures

Tags: packages

Could someone tell me if there are any packages of figures that are aimed at the medical area?

Commented on [Tex-Talk](http://tex-talk.net/2016/11/tikz-people/) and it seems to me that it is more or less the way.

Here is a rough idea of how I would like to insert the figures. They would be like icons.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

O coração (heart) é um órgão responsável pelo bombeamento de sangue para o corpo, ... \newline

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{heart.png} 
\label{heart}
\end{figure}

Os pulmões (lungs) são os órgãos responsáveis por captar o oxigênio e liberar na corrente sanguínea, ... \newline

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{lungs.png} 
\label{lungs}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Here is an example for [tikzpeople](http://tex-talk.net/2016/11/tikz-people/)

Comment: if you search for vector images there are lots and lots of available images in vector format, why do you need specific tex versions?

Comment: From what I have understood: you want something that will read your doc and make illustrations to it. Am I right? There is a neuronet that takes your description and draws it.

Comment: @MichaelFraiman Like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/375543/134085)

Comment: There are some heavy edits, as I see. So, you want to have sth like `\highlight{lugns}` and you will get lungs highlighted, then change to `\highlight{heart}` and the heart gets highlighted?

Comment: @MichaelFraiman We are progressing. This is the way. Sorry for not being able to be clear on the question. But you're helping me a lot.

Comment: @LCarvalho okay, this seems like a challenge. If you want somebody to answer I recommend you **(1)** clarify the answer by formulating your question, using proper tags and remaking the title; **(2)** add an MWE, at least something you have learned from the linked question.

Comment: I have zero idea what you are asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What graphics packages are there for creating graphics in LaTeX documents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-graphics-packages-are-there-for-creating-graphics-in-latex-documents)